# I have a client who is interested in getting raw data through the YT api. Is that possible?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a client who is interested in getting raw data such as views, view through rate through the YT api. Is that possible? The Google support team suggested posting in the forum.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow...What do you mean by raw data?  Please check the Help section to improve your question.  You can Edit your question over and over

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like most of what you're looking for would be available through the [YouTube Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/). Use it for reports on viewing activity, ad performance, etc.

If you want data about channels, videos, playlists and stuff like that, you'd use the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started).

Both APIs are very well documented, and a quick read of the intro pages should give you an idea of which is best suited to your needs.